# findstr regular expression missmatch

Tags: regex, windows-xp, command-line-interface

If I run this CLI command:

```
pdftotext -l 10 file.pdf - | findstr /i /r "isbn[0-9 xX\-]*"
```

I don't get a match.

If I output xpdf's pdftotext result to text file:

```
pdftotext -l 10 file.pdf file.txt
```

then parse this file in Kiki for example with the same pattern:

```
isbn[0-9 xX\-]*
```

I get expected results.

What could be wrong here?

*PS stdout from pdftotext is read correctly by findstr*

Comment: How do you know that "stdout from pdftotext is read correctly by findstr"? What happens when you do: type file.txt | findstr /i /r "isbn[0-9 xX\-]*"

Comment: I tested with simple literal search. It's same if I use type file.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried some sample inputs with `echo isbn1-23-4 | findstr` or similar?

To me it seems that Windows `findstr` doesn't understand the bracket `[0-9 xX\-]`. However, it seems that `echo isbn1-X23-4x | findstr /i /r "isbn[0123456789-xX]*"` works, so you might have some success with

```
pdftotext -l 10 file.pdf - | findstr /i /r "isbn[0123456789-xX]*"
```

Comment: Did you mean for your regexp to also match ISBNs containing space characters? I can't seem to get this to work with findstr...

Comment: Interestingly true. "isbn[0123456789-xX]*" works fine.
BTW if I run findstr/? is states that command supports ranges: "[x-y]    Range: any characters within the specified range"

Comment: There is space between 9 and x. In fact if I remove space from my range, it works also, although in both cases I get whole lines, not just the matched result i.e. ISBN 111111111x

Comment: Well, actually findstr returns lines, it can't return match. It's unclear to me why provided answer works because there is space between ISBN and number after, and why it doesn't work when I use space in regex pattern range, but I'll mark this as answered. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: As last comment :D I don't see point in using findstr regex feature in this case when same result is obtained just by using 'find /i "isbn"'. Cheers